# ¿Es posible usar eventos sin fecha fin? Fullcalendar.io

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

Buen día, quisiera saber si es posible crear en fullcalendar eventos sin una fecha fin. Estoy haciendo un control de acceso en el cual los trabajadores entran y se muestra la entrada a través de un evento.

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas la documentación, puedes ver que a un objeto de tipo `Event` se le puede pasar `null` en el atributo `end` para indicar que que el el evento no tiene definida su fecha de finalización:

> **`end`**: Date object that obeys the current timeZone. When an event ends. It could be null if an end wasn’t specified.

- https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object